# Developer settings on device for waitForDebugger?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adt

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107587/android-with-jdb-confusion-using-waitfordebugger/3471400#3471400) and [here](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/04/android-quick-tip-1-liner-to-make-the-vm-wait-for-debugger-to-connect/#comments) that there is a device setting to support equivalent behavior to inserting `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()` in your application.

Apparently, there is a pre-deployed tool on the emulator called `dev tools` that provides this option.  It's there in the application menu.

Can I install dev tools on a real device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [pull the DevTools application from an emulator and push it to a real device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-devtools.html).

Answer (score 0):

The dev tools is something that exists in the emulator, but not in real devices.
AFAIK it can't be installed either.

Comment: Actually you can install Dev Tools on a real device. But there are some caveats (the System Image and Dev Tools must be signed with the same key). http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html.